# Copy constructor for a doubly linked list, issue with head initalization

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a copy constructor for a templated, double-linked list...
Here's what I have so far:

```
// Copy Constructor
template <typename Item>
LinkedList<Item>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<Item> &s){
    // Create an iterator for the other list
    ListNode<Item> *node = s.head;
    // Create a reference to use as an iterator for the new list
    // Set it to the address of head of the new list
    ListNode<Item> **curr_node = &head;
    // Create a placeholder for the address of the previous node
    ListNode<Item> *prev_node = NULL;
    while(node != NULL){
            *curr_node = new ListNode<Item>;
            // If a prev_node address has been saved, initialize the new node's prev value
            // If a prev_node hasn't been saved yet, this means it is the head and prev should
            // be initialized to NULL 
            (*curr_node)->prev = prev_node;
            // Set the new node data fields to that of the node in the other list
            (*curr_node)->data = node->data;

            // -------- Set up for next iteration ------- 
            // Save the address of the current node to be used in the next node's prev_node 
            prev_node = *curr_node;
            // Set the curr_node pointer to the address of the next node in the new list 
            curr_node = &((*curr_node)->next);
            // Set the node pointer to the next node in other list
            node = node->next;
    }
    // Set the tail after all the nodes have been copied
    tail = prev_node;
}
```

When I call this code in my tester:

```
LinkedList<int> ll;
ll.insert_back(5); 
ll.insert_back(10);
ll.insert_back(15);
LinkedList<int> ll1 = ll;
cout << "Printing contents of copied list: "; ll1.print();
```

I get this error in valgrind:

```
Contents of list to be copied: [5] -> [10] -> [15]
==4624== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4624==    at 0x401077: LinkedList<int>::print() (LinkedList.cc:159)
==4624==    by 0x400D7B: main (tester.cpp:54)
==4624== 
==4624== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4624==    at 0x40109E: LinkedList<int>::print() (LinkedList.cc:155)
==4624==    by 0x400D7B: main (tester.cpp:54)
```

Line 153, 155, 159 of my print() function:

```
153: ListNode<Item> *end = head;
155: while(end != NULL){
159: if(end->next != NULL)
```

So I draw the conclusion that end is never initialized meaning that head is NULL or set to some junk value... Anyone have any thoughts on this? Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would want to replace the line

```
curr_node = &((*curr_node)->next);
```

with

```
*curr_node = &(node->next);
```

since `curr_node` was set to a `new ListNode<Item>` earlier inside the while loop.

Just curious, why is curr_node a pointer to a pointer to a node?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is set curr_node equal to the the address that the current node's next field is set to, so that I can initialize it with the value of the other list's next node.
Setting *curr_node = &(node->next) would be setting it equal to the address of the list node that I'm trying to copy over into the new list.

Comment: curr_node = &((*curr_node)->next) sets curr_node equal to the address of what the current node's next is.  Dereferencing that allows for initialization of the next value in the list. I don't know a better way to do this.

Comment: When you set `*curr_node = new ListNode<Item>;` you call the default constructor for `ListNode<Item>` and `(*curr_node)->next` is initialized to whatever the constructor for `ListNode<Item>` puts there. Most likely, it points to `NULL` but it might be uninitialized. What does the constructor look like?

Comment: It initializes next and prev to null.